# FirebaseMessage showing multiple notifications

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, message

I read topics on stackoverflow and i didn't found the answer. Everything works fine with notifications, but the problem is that if I call the function that send notification more than 1 time it sends more than 1 notification per time. For example, if I click on the list index to send notification for certain token it sends normal but if I click again it sends 2 times and if I click again it sends 3 times etc... How can I solve this problem?

```
 sendNotificationAndroid('Example of title', token);
```

```
  sendNotificationAndroid(String title, String token)async{

    final data = {
      'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
      'id': '1',
      'status': 'done',
      'message': title,
    };

    try{
      http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),headers: <String,String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'key=XXXXXXXXXX'
      },
          body: jsonEncode(<String,dynamic>{
            'notification': <String,dynamic> {'title': title,'body': 'Example'},
            'priority': 'high',
            'data': data,
            'to': '$token'
          })
      );


      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        print("Yeh notificatin is sended");
      }else{
        print("Error");
      }

    }catch(e){

    }

  }
```

OBS: I'm calling the function sendNotificationAndroid inside a listen (OnTap of List tile in a Stream builder);

```
initState(){
    super.initState();
  var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid,);
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
      LocalNotificationService.display(event);
    });
  }
```

Comment: How do you to trigger sending a  notification?

Comment: In initState, i will edit the post

Answer (score 1):

Every time `initState` is called a new listener is added. `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` should be called once.

Comment: Where can I put the listen? I'm sorry, i'm kinda new to flutter

Comment: If i don't put on initstate the notifications on foreground doesn't appears

Comment: Put it in the place it is only called once e.g. higher in the widget tree.

Comment: I've tried to put in a place where is called once but it didnt solved. The problem ( i think so ) is that the notification have the same id and its not replacing the old one. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is most likely caused by the fact that you are not canceling the previously scheduled notifications before scheduling new ones. To solve this problem, you should cancel the previously scheduled notifications before scheduling new ones.

You can achieve this by keeping track of the notification ID that is returned by the flutter_local_notifications package when you schedule a notification. Then, when you want to send a new notification, you can first cancel the previously scheduled notification with that ID using the cancel method of the FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin class.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how you can achieve this:

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

// Keep track of the notification IDs
int notificationId = 0;

// Schedule a notification
Future<void> scheduleNotification(String token) async {
// Cancel the previously scheduled notification, if any
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(notificationId);

// Increment the notification ID
notificationId++;

// Construct the notification details
final AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
  AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your_channel_id', 'your_channel_name', 'your_channel_description',
      importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.high, showWhen: false);
final NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
  NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

// Schedule the notification
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
  notificationId,
  'Notification title',
  'Notification body',
  platformChannelSpecifics,
  payload: token);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Before showing notification you can cancel previous notification

```
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
```

or by id.